# Location in syntax trees

Tags: parsing, ocaml

When writing a parser, I want to remember the *location* of lexemes found, so that I can report useful error messages to the programmer, as in “if-less else on line 23” or ”unexpected character on line 45, character 6” or “variable not defined” or something similar.  But once I have built the syntax tree, I will transform it in several ways, optimizing or expanding some kind of macros.  The transformations produce or rearrange lexemes which do not have a meaningful location.

Therefore it seems that the type representing the syntax tree should come in two flavor, a flavor with locations decorating lexemes and a flavor without lexemes. Ideally we would like to work with a purely abstract syntax tree, as defined in the [OCaml book](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora058.html):

```
# type unr_op = UMINUS | NOT  ;;
# type bin_op = PLUS | MINUS | MULT | DIV | MOD  
             | EQUAL | LESS | LESSEQ | GREAT | GREATEQ | DIFF 
             | AND | OR  ;;
# type expression = 
     ExpInt of int 
   | ExpVar of string
   | ExpStr of string 
   | ExpUnr of unr_op * expression
   | ExpBin of expression * bin_op * expression  ;;
# type command = 
     Rem of string
   | Goto of int 
   | Print of expression
   | Input of string 
   | If of expression * int 
   | Let of string * expression  ;;
# type line = { num : int ; cmd : command }  ;;
# type program = line list  ;;
```

We should be allowed to totally forget about locations when working on that tree and have special functions to map an `expression` back to its location (for instance), that we could use in case of emergency.

What is the best way to define such a type in OCaml or to handle lexeme positions?

Comment: The question is not very clear to me, but OCaml compiler's source code around parsing/ and typing/ is a full detailed example of such AST with locations + transformation.

Comment: Define your tree node with an extra slot, *position*.   Convention: when position not zero, it provides precise position information; when zero, there is "no position".

Comment: @camlspotter I added some details in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to work always with AST nodes fully annotated with the locations. For example:

```
type expression = {
  expr_desc : expr_desc;
  expr_loc : Lexing.position * Lexing.position; (* start and end *)
}

and expr_desc =
     ExpInt of int 
   | ExpVar of string
   | ExpStr of string 
   | ExpUnr of unr_op * expression
   | ExpBin of expression * bin_op * expression
```

Your idea, keeping the AST free of locations and writing a function to retrieve the missing locations is not a good idea, I believe. Such a function should require searching by pointer equivalence of AST nodes or something similar, which does not really scale.

I strongly recommend to look though OCaml compiler's `parser.mly` which is a full scale example of AST with locations.